# Android Webview with Proxy Timeout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, http-proxy

I've got a problem with Xamarin.Android's webview in combination with a proxy.

Scenario:

A Xamarin.Android application only consisting of a WebView that tries to load "http://google.com".

When I'm on a wifi without proxy it works fine.

When my wifi uses a proxy to access the internet it is timing out, the proxy settings of the wifi connection are not getting respected by the webview. With the Chrome browser on the tablet it works fine though.

I tried everything I could find but nothing seems to work...
Those methods are obsolete and returning null or for the port -1.

```
Android.Net.Proxy.GetHost(this.ApplicationContext);
Android.Net.Proxy.GetPort(this.ApplicationContext);
Java.Lang.JavaSystem.GetProperty("http.proxyPort");
Java.Lang.JavaSystem.GetProperty("http.proxyHost");
```

So my question is:
How can I get the webview to work with the proxy set on the wifi?

I'm blocked since a week due to that problem on a project and very thankfull very every help I can get.

Code:

```
        // Inflate layout and find view
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.cas_login);
        WebView wv = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.casWebView);

        // Get URLs
        string sessionId = UVM.GetJSessionId();
        string apiUri = App.GetApiURI();
        string websiteUrl = App.GetWebsiteUri();
        string websiteRedirectUrl = websiteUrl + "api/myInfo/infos";
        string requestUrl = $"{apiUri}login?requestUrl={websiteRedirectUrl}";

        // Setup webView
        wv.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        wv.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        wv.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = true;
        wv.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        wv.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
        wv.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
        wv.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.Settings.UserAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36";
        wv.Settings.MixedContentMode = MixedContentHandling.AlwaysAllow;

        wv.SetWebViewClient(new CasWebViewClient(websiteRedirectUrl, ShowMainActivity));
        //wv.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        WebView.EnablePlatformNotifications();

        CookieManager.Instance.SetCookie(websiteUrl, sessionId);

        // Load URL
        _logger.LogMessage(LogLevel.Debug, "CasLogin.cs OnCreate", "Loading page: " + requestUrl);
        wv.LoadUrl(requestUrl);
```

PS: If I use the WebChromeClient it works fine, it opens chrome and the page loads fine.

Comment: by proxy what exactly do you mean, if i'm not wrong you mean that your wifi is using a proxy ip?

Comment: Yeah the wifi connection uses a proxy and on the edit proxy for wifi screen I saw a notification (too late obviously) that it is not possible for apps to use the wifi proxy setting.

Comment: Well anyways closing this then

Comment: Nevermind, while setting the wifi proxy it even gives a warning that the proxy will only be used be the browser and not by other apps => ergo the webview in my application isn't able to connect.
-------- CLOSED ----------